# Is there any downside with 424 status code

Tags: stripe-payments, http-status-codes

When I google to find some examples with 424 status code, actually there are not many. And I find it really useful to use, for example in cases when dependency fails due to users "problem".
Particularly, in case of insufficient balance
https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes#balance_insufficient Stripe will fail, so in this case I find 424 is really appropriate.

So, would like to know, is there any downside using 424 status code.

Comment: Actually for stripe insufficient balance, it returns `402` which is `payment required`. 402 is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: There is no 'downside' in using this code for a scenario as long as it's clearly stated and documented. What's your question though? what would you like to use this code returned for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any downside, and reading through the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918), and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) it seems safe to use it. If the "downside" you are referring to would be some functionality built into the web browser to do redirect or something, you should be fine.
If the consumer of your API has rules, they would just need to add to any logic that have for handling specific HttpStatusCodes.
Feel free to use the status code.